# Unable to upgrade due to many dependency issues with libc6 and util-linux

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

So I haven't been on my Ubuntu machine in a while, and it's still running 16.04. I decided to update and upgrade everything and then upgrade to 18.04. But when trying to run `apt upgrade` I ran into a handful of problems I think eventually rooting to a broken `util-linux` package. I decided to try to reinstall it from the deb package on the Ubuntu website but there were a couple other outdated dependencies which I subsequently installed from the website as well, resulting in a chain of installations that eventually ended at libc6 and failed with no clear explanation. Now whenever I try to do anything with apt I get errors such as `libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed`, just like 100 more. At the beginning it advises to run `apt-get -f install` to fix the issues but doing so fails because of `linux-util`. With that I am completely lost. If anyone has any idea what is happening please let me know. I can share whatever other information is needed to understand the issue better.

Edits

Here's the full output after running `apt-get upgrade`: https://pastebin.com/cyXf81y8

And after running `apt-get -f install`: https://pastebin.com/Y4EkA88E

`apt-get update` runs successfully barring a couple of warnings: https://pastebin.com/gtL8trqq

Comment: Providing the full message may help us to understand, and provide useful answers. Both official sources (Xenial & Bionic) meet that requirement (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libdrm-radeon1 https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libdrm-radeon1) unless you weren't fully updated on xenial, however without full messages we cannot provide more specific advice. How did you upgrade?  (official way, or something else), and have you checked your sources?  (the usual issue is 3rd party packages creating issues on *release-upgrade* which is seen by reading messages you didn't provide).

Comment: To upgrade to *bionic* or 18.04, the best place to go is the release notes - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes

Comment: Updated my answer with full outputs, please let me know if you would like to see the output of any other commands. I definitely wasn't fully updated on xenial since it has been a while since I've used this computer (like 8 months), but I've just been using apt to try to upgrade (except for the dependencies I mentioned that I got off of the online Ubuntu package directory), the GUI is having all sorts of its own problems. That said I don't think anything is 3rd party.

Comment: Commands are useful to help fully appreciate the listing being read. I picked a message and Xenial provides the required package of libc6-dev (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libc6-dev&searchon=names) so did you update your package lists?   I'd suggest stepping back to `sudo apt update` and perusing that output to ensure everything is there is correct, as your output highlights likely operator mistake (prior step `sudo apt-get update` issue ignored) OR sources issue (`sudo apt-get update` prior step should have detected issue with missing lines).

Comment: @guiverc Sorry I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at. I did run `apt-get update` with no issues (there are a couple of warnings saying some signatures use weak digest algorithms but no errors). It's in the next step, running `apt-get upgrade`, where all my problems started.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think the warnings are significant on the `update` however, since again they are just saying that some signatures use weak digest algorithms. I updated my question with that output as well nonetheless.

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato, You're right about the warning. While it is noteworthy, there isn't anything that you can do about it, other than maybe just exclude those sources until they upgrade from SHA1. If you found a solution, you should write, and accept, your own answer here to let the community know what solved your problem.

Comment: You were right about warning being of no value (I'd have fixed it though thru removal), the `apt update` messages show only amd64, but your error messages show need for i386 packages, what architecture(s) do you have enabled?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input! I definitely will if I can find the solution, but that is a really big if since again I am really lost right now.

Comment: I'm running on a 64-bit architecture, so yes the i386 packages really add to my confusion.

Comment: Pick a package, and try and look at what requires it, eg. "lib32gcc1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.2.4)" so `apt-cache rdepends lib32gcc1`  (though I picked lib32gcc at random, you may want to pick a package that'll be used by fewer, eg. libmng2 maybe, again picked quickly).  To *release-upgrades* 3rd party packages usually create the issues, you have loads of 3rd party sources (many non-Ubuntu too)  A re-install (no-format, something-else) maybe easier given 3rd party..

Comment: Running that command does list several dependencies--what exactly does that mean? And is there a way to re-install the OS without formatting?

Comment: Given the amount of 3rd party (PPA & non-Ubuntu) sources you have, re-install is what I'd do. Firstly backup, then assuming desktop you use *something-else*, select existing partitions ensuring you don't have format checked, it'll note your installed packages, erase system directories, install, add back previously noted additional packages you'd installed (if available on new release), then ask to reboot. It won't touch any user file (unless you formatted). Server programs can store *conf* files in system directories so can be impacted & why I highlight desktop which store *conf* in $HOME

Answer (score 0):

remove your Panasonic scanner driver and [macchanger](https://github.com/shilch/macchanger)
their init-scripts have no lsb tag meaning
[sorry debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts)

After that

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a   && sudo apt -f install
```